# GWT - Execute another URL in a event

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I'm trying implement a internationalization in GWT. I finished and this works. But I wanna execute the URL with parameter &locale=de when I click in a button.

For example:

Original URL -> `/* http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 */`

When I click on the button, I wanna execute this URL 
-> `/* http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&locale=de */`

There's a way to do this?

Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the button handler

```
 Window.Location.replace(Window.Location.getPath() + 
                            Window.Location.getQueryString() +"&locale=de");
```